# Filter RDD by Date joda/scala/spark

Tags: scala, date, apache-spark, filter, jodatime

I have an RDD in spark which is essentially (timestamp, id), where the timestamp is joda DateTime of the form yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm. The RDD is of class;

```
case class myRDD(timestamp: org.joda.time.DateTime, id: String)
```

I am using Spark and Scala.

I want to filter the data to only have a certain day i.e. 2000/01/01, and return something of the form (timestamp, id), but am unsure how to use filter() with the joda timestamp. I have created the start and end of the interval I want to filter by the following;

```
val start = myFormat.parseDateTime("2000/01/01 00:00")
val end = myFormat.parseDateTime("2000/01/02 00:00”)
```

but I do not know how to apply this to an RDD, or even if this is the best way to approach this. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is timestamp a string, or a joda DateTime?

Comment: @soote the timestamp is a joda DateTime, the class I created is of the form; `case class rdd(timestamp: org.joda.time.DateTime, id: String)`

Answer (score 1):

For just 1 day:

```
rdd.filter( (timestamp, id) => 
    timestamp.withTimeAtStartOfDay.equals(dayYouWant.withtimeAtStartOfDay) )
```

For a range of days:

```
rdd.filter( (timestamp, id) => 
    new Interval(start, end).contains(timestamp) )
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have been tinkering with the code you suggested but I am still receiving errors, mainly; `error: wrong number of parameters; expected = 1`

Comment: @ellaf I wrote it to take a tuple of 2 params (timestamp and it), you only have 1 param (your rdd case class). So try replacing the tuple with your case class.